# Du moins / au moins pas immédiatement

Tags: sens, adverbes

Bonjour,

A propose à B de se joindre à son équipe. A hésite. Il pense :

> Toujours est-il que je ne peux pas accepter sa proposition, **du moins**
> pas immédiatement.
>
> Toujours est-il que je ne peux pas accepter sa proposition, **au moins**
> pas immédiatement.

Je pense que les deux variantes sont possibles ici, pourtant je n'arrive pas à saisir la différence entre "du moins" et "au moins" ici. Je les traduirais pas le même mot...

Comment: Je ne crois pas que *au moins* soit possible ici. Peut-être à l'oral, mais ça sonne quand même faux à mes oreilles.

Answer (score 4):

Seul *du moins* (ou tout du moins) est possible ici. *Du moins* veut dire *en tous cas*, *néanmoins*.

> Toujours est-il que je ne peux pas accepter sa proposition, du moins pas immédiatement.

*Au moins* veut dire *au minimum* (« Au moins 31 migrants ont perdu la vie dans la Manche », *seulement* (« Si au moins il faisait beau demain ! »).

**[Orthodidacte](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/orthographe-du-moins) :**

> L’expression ***du moins*** est un connecteur qui s’utilise pour exprimer une restriction, pour apporter une rectification à ce qu’on vient de dire ou d’écrire. Exemple : *les trains sont rarement à l’heure, du moins c’est ce qu’on dit.*

> ***Du moins ou au moins* ?**

> Il existe aussi en français l’expression ***au moins***, qui ne doit pas être confondue avec ***du moins***. Elle s’emploie dans deux cas de figure. Premier cas : pour indiquer un minimum. Exemple : *il faut au moins une heure de train pour y aller* (c’est-à-dire « au minimum »).
> Et deuxième cas, à l’oral, avec le sens de « l’avantage, c’est que… ». Exemple : *au moins, comme ça, c’est clair !*

Comment: Merci. Antidote propose cette définition : Le moins qu’on puisse dire de quelque chose est cela (et c’est probablement plus fort que cela). _Les méthodes employées étaient, au moins, radicales._ Donc, "au moins" decrait convenir dans ma phrase, à mon avis. En tout cas, je le traduis par le même mot...

Comment: @Oreste  *Le moins  qu'on puisse dire de quelque chose*  n'a rien à voir avec *du moins*. Et je n'emploierais pas *au  moins* dans ta phrase. *Du moins* et *au moins* ne sont pas vraiment synonymes. Voir : https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/moins.   J'ai ajouté une référence dans la réponse, tu peux en trouver d'autres. Voir aussi le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moins). Ce qui te fais peut-être  croire qu'ils sont synonymes c'est parce qu'en anglais les deux se traduisent en général par *at least*.

Comment: @Oreste In English [at least](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_least) has two meanigns. When in English "at least" means "anyway", "in any case",  it's *du moins* in French. When in English "at least" means "at the minimum" it's *au moins* in French. Do you mean "at the minimum" in your sentence? It sounds weird to me, to say the least.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. " Le moins qu'on puisse dire de quelque chose n'a rien à voir avec du moins" --- Avec "au moins" tu voulais dire, non ? J'ai recopié la définition d'Antidote.  // "When in English "at least" means "anyway", "in any case", it's du moins in French. When in English "at least" means "at the minimum" it's au moins in French." --- OK, je comprends mieux. Non, je ne voulais pas dire "at the minimum".

Comment: Le moins qu’on puisse dire de quelque chose est cela (et c’est probablement plus fort que cela) = au moins ? OK, je pense que je comprends...

Comment: @Oreste , *Le moins qu'on puisse dire de quelque chose *→ the least that can be said about .... "The least"  (superlative of less/little) is not "at least" (prepositional phrase). "The least" → *le moins*

Answer (score 2):

Ces deux locutions sont peu pratiques parce qu'elles se confondent facilement.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moins)) **a) Au moins**
> − En prenant la plus faible estimation.
> ♦ Il doit être au moins licencié, en droit ou ès sciences (Romains, Hommes bonne vol., 1932, p.147).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moins)) **d) Du moins**
> − [Dans un système oppositionnel (souvent précédé de *ou* ou figurant dans une incise) sert à restreindre une assertion]
> ♦ Il nous fallut, du moins pour quelques temps, renoncer au spectacle dont on nous avait flattés (Dusaulx, Voy. Barège, t.1, 1796, p.233).Vous êtes charmante, belle Raimonde, ou du moins je suis charmé (Stendhal, L. Leuwen, t.3, 1836, p.32).
> ♦ Elle aimait son fiancé, du moins elle croyait l'aimer (Sandeau, Mlle de La Seiglière, 1848, p.104).
> **[En corrélation avec sinon]**
> ♦ Dès lors il était, sinon agréable, du moins naturel et honorable d'être à ce point méconnu par eux (Larbaud, Journal, 1935, p.359).Elle était sinon mince, du moins pas grasse (Triolet, Prem. accroc, 1945, p.229).
> **[Portant sur l'énonciation] Synon. de au moins**, au minimum.
> ♦ Vous êtes du moins Andalouse. Il me semble le reconnaître à votre doux parler (Mérimée, Carmen, 1847, p.20).
> ♦ S'il a tous ces torts mystérieux, existe-t-il, du moins, quelqu'un qui ne les ait pas? (Gobineau, Pléiades, 1874, p.106).

D'après les définitions du TLFi la seule possibilité est bien « du moins », comme l'affirme la réponse de [**user None**](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49167/17649). Il n'y pas lieu de formuler une estimation pour « maintenant » ;  des estimations sont formulables pour « pas avant quelques temps », « pas avant deux semaines », « pas avant l'année prochaine ». Tout ce que l'auteur peut faire pour exclure le point de départ, c'est de mettre ce point de départ en opposition à des temps à venir: « quoi qu'il en soit de ce que je pourrais faire, ce ne sera pas fait maintenant ».

L'usage suivant serait correct.

- Toujours est-il que je ne peux pas accepter sa proposition, au moins pas avant qu'elle n'ait changé certaines de ses décisions.

D'après la synonymie que la définition souligne, on pourrait de façon équivalente utiliser la phrase suivante.

- Toujours est-il que je ne peux pas accepter sa proposition, du moins pas avant qu'elle n'ait changé certaines de ses décisions.

On s'apercevra néanmoins que les gens ne font pas toujours cette distinction, ce que montre les sept références suivantes, dans lesquelles « au moins » est utilisé à la place de « du moins ».

([réf. 1, 2008](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Un_industriel_au_c%C5%93ur_de_l_Europe/VA4GLRdjN2sC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22au+moins+pas%22&pg=PA158&printsec=frontcover)) Vous n'avez pas de raison de descendre de voiture, au moins pas pour vous en éloigner.

([réf. 2, 2020](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_Amour_au_temps_de_l_Alzheimer_ou_de_l/RbHeDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22au+moins+pas%22&pg=PT58&printsec=frontcover)) Et petit à petit, j'avance, par essai et erreur, mais au moins pas à l'aveugle.

([réf. 3, 2016](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Pape_et_Concile_au_XIXe_si%C3%A8cle/wTwoDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22au+moins+pas%22&pg=PT154&printsec=frontcover)) Donc, encore une fois, quand nous devrions ne pas avoir eu les madones de Raphël, nous n'aurions au moins pas cet effacement déplorable du Dieu spirituel, invisible, par une divinité présente et matérielle, objet de tous les honneurs, ...

([réf. 4, 1986](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/%C3%80_pas_de_g%C3%A9ant/BtVCEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22au+moins+pas%22&pg=PT201&printsec=frontcover)) Là au moins pas de danger, on ne pense qu'à une chose : apprendre.

([réf. 5, 1846](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Revue_suisse/wQM7AAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22au+moins+pas%22&pg=PA36&printsec=frontcover)) C'est le cas de dire : Heureux ceux qui , n'ayant point tant d'argent , n'ont au moins pas tant de souci de ce côté ! Si ne voilà pas un beau prèche , nous renonçons à faire des sermons ;

([réf. 6, 2003](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/%C3%89conomies_et_soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9s/-Mu2AAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22au+moins+pas%22&dq=%22au+moins+pas%22&printsec=frontcover)) Au moins pas toujours. Lorsqu'il fait allusion à « notre discipline », c'est à l'économie politique qu'il songe,

([réf. 7, 1931](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Annales/vwsTAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22au+moins+pas%22&dq=%22au+moins+pas%22&printsec=frontcover)) Il y a des explications plausibles, il n'y en a pas d'obligatoires, au moins pas en statistique.